# Trying to rewrite variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
    print("Please enter some integers to average. Enter 0 to indicate you are done.")

#part (a) -- what are the initial values for these variables?
#incomplete
done = 0
mySum = 0
count =  0   
while not done:
    valid = False #don't yet have a valid input
    while not valid: #this loop keeps attempting to get input until the user enters an integer
        try:
            num = int(input())
            valid = True #now the input is valid, and can use it
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer.")  
    if num == 0:
        break
        mySum = sum(num)
        count = len(num)
        #part (b) -- fill in the inside of this if statement
        #incomplete


    else: print num  #part (c) -- if num is not zero, then... fill in the code
        #incomplete


avg = mySum / count #calculates average
print("The average is", avg) #prints average
```

Excuse the comments as this is an assignment from an instructor. As you can see, line 28 of the code shows a divide by zero error for variable mySum. In the while loop I overwrote(or at least tried to) mySum, but still got the division error. Am I going about this correctly or is there some syntax I'm not following?

EDIT: New attempt:

```
#part (a) -- what are the initial values for these variables?
#incomplete
done = 0
mySum = [] 
count =  len(mySum)  

while not done:
    valid = False #don't yet have a valid input
    while not valid: #this loop keeps attempting to get input until the user enters an integer
        try:
            num = int(input())
            valid = True #now the input is valid, and can use it
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer.")  
    if num == 0:
        break
        #part (b) -- fill in the inside of this if statement
        #incomplete


    else: mySum.append(num)
    count +=1#part (c) -- if num is not zero, then... fill in the code
        #incomplete


avg = sum(mySum) / count #calculates average

if len(mySum) == 0:
    print "You haven't entered any number"
else: print ("The average is", avg)
```

Comment: That should be better

Comment: ```break``` followed by other instructions is alone a bad sign! (and hardcore programmers will tell you: do not use break)

Comment: @sascha - There's nothing inherently wrong with `break`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The same could be said about goto; but well... two groups of people...

Comment: @sascha - No, it couldn't. `goto` has no place in modern programming languages. `break` and `continue` do. It's possible to misuse them, but that's true of anything.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 [Some reading](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices). Like i said. Two groups...

Comment: @sascha - The first half dozen answers to that question state that there's nothing inherently wrong with `break` and `continue`, which seems to confirm that telling people not to use them, suggesting that "hardcore programmers" recommend against them, or implying that anyone who uses them is not a "hardcore programmer" is, quite frankly, nonsense.

Comment: @sascha: This is a false dichotomy. There's a continuum between allowing unrestricted goto and disallowing any unstructured jumps. Both extremes are bad, as are people who are blindly espousing them. For one thing, if you disallow break, you must also disallow exceptions (which are less explicit, and thus more dangerous) - and you can't do Python without exceptions. The sane majority is pretty much agreed on "as long as your functions are less than one screenful, break is good, even labeled (multi-level) break; exceptions are good; unrestricted goto is bad".

Comment: @Amadan - Exactly. `break` and `continue` can easily be used in a perfectly legitimate fashion, meaning that there's nothing inherently wrong with them. I'd much rather see a properly-used `break` than a `global` (or worse, `globals()`). :P

Answer (score 0):

Denominator cannot be zero. In this case, count is zero.

You may need to use count += 1 instead of count = len(num).

You should check whether the denominator is zero before you do the division.

Suggestion: study python 3 instead of python 2.7. Python 2 will be finally replaced by python 3.

```
    mySum = 0
    count = 0
    while True:  # this loop keeps attempting to get input until the user enters        an integer
        try:
            num = int(input("input a num "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer.")
            continue
        if num == 0:
            break
        else:
            mySum += num
            count += 1
            print(num)
    avg = mySum / count if count else 0
    print("The average is", avg)  # prints average
```

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code. The new code is what I actually have

Answer (score 0):

The "divide by zero" is a consequence of other problems in your code (or incompleteness of it). The proximate cause can be understood from the message: you are dividing by `0`, which means `count` is `0` at that point, which means you haven't actually tracked the numbers you put in. This, in turn, is - because you don't do anything with the numbers you put in.

- In case `num == 0`, you immediately `break` the loop; the two statements below do not execute.
- In case of not `num == 0`, you just print the number; there is not storing of a number into an array that you can `sum` later, there is no `+=` summing in an interim variable, and there is certainly no incrementing of `count`.

There is two basic ways to do this, hinted to by the above:

List: Make an empty list outside the loop, when 0 is entered just break, otherwise add the new number to the list. After the loop, check the length: if it's zero, complain that no numbers have been entered, otherwise divide the sum by the length. No `count` required.

Running total: Initialize `total` and `count` variables to `0` outside the loop; again, just break on a `0`, otherwise add one to the count and the number to the total. After the loop, do the same, just with `total` and `count` instead of with `sum` and `len`.

Comment: Would it work if I created an array inside the if statement for sum and len to work?

Comment: Creating an array *inside* the `if` is not *quite* correct. I edited the post with the approaches to take.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you for the info, I figured out the main problem. Another problem has arisen where when the user types "0", it is also appended to the list and used in the average count. I was under the impression that the break would stop the appending of the number 0.

Comment: Post the new code in the question at the bottom and I'll take a look.

Comment: Should be there now

Comment: In your latest code, `0` is not appended to the list, it works correctly. What makes you think it does? Meanwhile, stylistically there are some things one could improve. First of all, you really shouldn't use `else: same_row_stuff`, and you really shouldn't mix the indented `if` section with same-line `else` section: pick one or the other (preferably indenting both). Secondly, `else` is not really needed, since you are breaking in the `if`: any following lines will be only executed if the `if` is not true.

Comment: And finally, if you keep the `else`, just to have the logic clear, either both of those lines should be inside the `else`, or neither. Because of the `break`, the effect is the same, but it is much harder to read, and easy to make a mistake if you refactor your code in the future.

Comment: I thought it was because when trying to get the average of numbers 1,2,3,and 4, the program returns 2. Entering zero was supposed to let the program know that the there will be no more inputs and zero shouldn't be included, if that makes sense.

Comment: `sum([1, 2, 3, 4])` is `10`; in Python 2, `10 / 4` is `2` (division of two integers will give an integral result). Either start using Python3, make Python2 into fake Python3 using `from __future__ import division` at the top, or change `sum(mySum) / count` into `float(sum(mySum)) / count`.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for your input. I actually understand this now.